# Spring boot/Hibernate: Tables not getting created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My application was creating tables earlier. I was running into "detached entity passed to persist" exception during which I found out that the date/time was null. To fix the issue so that I can debug the problem, I dropped all the tables in the dev environment and re-ran the application. Now my tables are no longer getting created.

Any suggestions on what is that I messed up?

Relevant application.properties are as below:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXX
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

I am seeing below errors during startup:

```
2022-03-07 14:13:36.666 DEBUG 37790 --- [main] .h.t.s.s.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator : No actions specified; doing nothing
2022-03-07 14:13:36.667 DEBUG 37790 --- [main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : No JtaPlatform was specified, checking resolver
2022-03-07 14:13:36.667 DEBUG 37790 --- [main] h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformResolverInitiator : No JtaPlatformResolver was specified, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver]
2022-03-07 14:13:36.671 DEBUG 37790 --- [main] .h.e.t.j.p.i.StandardJtaPlatformResolver : Could not resolve JtaPlatform, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-03-07 14:13:36.671  INFO 37790 --- [main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-03-07 14:13:36.672 DEBUG 37790 --- [main] o.h.q.s.NamedQueryRepository             : Checking 0 named HQL queries
2022-03-07 14:13:36.672 DEBUG 37790 --- [main] o.h.q.s.NamedQueryRepository             : Checking 0 named SQL queries
```

I do see that the LoadPlan is properly getting created. I tried with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think as you use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` if you application runs normally you will find your tables but if crashed or throws error the spring make rollback to created tables if any